# On Android, can I point a file to a folder on the file system so that it syncs to Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android, sync

I have an application that generates a file, and I'd like to have this file automatically sync to Ubuntu One. At the moment, I'm happy for it just to go in the 'Ubuntu One' folder, but being able to specify an alternate folder in my U1 account would also be cool.

As it stands, the only way I know how to do this is to generate the file that gets saved to some folder, then open the Ubuntu One android app, and specify to add a new file, pointing to the file that was generated.

Since the application that generates the file allows to me to specify the path, what I want to be able to do is to point it to the 'Ubuntu One' folder so that it gets synced to my account, without needing to add that extra step.

I've had a look in the file system and can see: `/sdcard0/u1/Ubuntu\ One`, but this seems to be only to store files that you specifically select from the app. I guess the android app doesn't have a daemon watching folders to auto push new files to U1 - other than perhaps pointing it to a pictures folder, since there is that auto upload photo's option.

Comment: Are you creating this application yourself? or is it one you have downloaded?

Comment: Just one that I have downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu One Files currently does not provide sync features, besides auto-upload of photos. We do have sync on the roadmap. The ETA is not close, though, as we only have one Android dev on the team.